# Taps per minute iOS programming

Tags: iphone, ios, time

I am trying to get the rate per minute that someone is pushing a button on iOS.When they press the button, a label is updated with the presses per minute. I have the code mostly working, but it is spitting out large positive/large negative numbers for the rate. I think it is in my math for computing the average. Any help would be appreciated and if you need any more information please let me know!

```
- (IBAction)countStroke:(id)sender {
    double avg;
    double start = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];


    if(start - endStroke > 60){
        count = 0;
    }

    if(count == 0){
        NSString *firststroke = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"First Stroke"];
        self.label.text = firststroke;
        endStroke = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        count ++;

    }
    else {
    endStroke = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    avg = ((60000 * count)/(endStroke - start));
    NSString *rate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", avg];
    self.label.text = rate;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d`  is used for integer values. Use `%f` instead

Comment: Also, using `%d` would have been causing a warning. You (the OP) shouldn't ignore warnings without a good reason.

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the negative numbers and added the decimals. I forgot to add I  need to round to the nearest number, but that should not be hard.

Comment: It did not have a warning oddly. I use those heavily for the most part which is also why I am having more trouble. I am new to this, so is there a way to set warning levels?

Comment: I'm not sure compiler recognizes these issues and marks as warning.

Comment: THanks! That was the problem and you are right the compiler does not catch those mistakes. I also am stupid and had a few too many zeros on  my average algorithm.... BIG HELP!

Comment: Oh, my bad—the compiler will warn you if you make the same mistake with `NSLog`, but not something like `stringWithFormat:`.